# coreNLPDependencyParser output explanation

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, dependency-parsing

i am running coreNLPDependencyParser for a sentence

> The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.

and i am getting output in this way

```
The     DT      4       det
quick   JJ      4       amod
brown   JJ      4       amod
fox     NN      5       nsubj
jumps   VBZ     0       ROOT
over    IN      9       case
the     DT      9       det
lazy    JJ      9       amod
dog     NN      5       nmod
.       .       5       punct
```

i ran the same input in stanfordDependencyParser and the output is same with different representation

**My question is**
if you see the third column it is giving some score sort of thing, i assumed it to be depth in the tree but its not correct

it is not mentioned anywhere what exactly the score is .

you can see tree [here](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.parse.html?highlight=stanford)

please enlighten me on output representation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each value in the third column is a directed edge in the dependency tree. For example:

- The head/governor of "quick" is token 4: "fox", and "quick" is a modifier of "fox" (amod)
- The head/governor of "fox" is token 5: "jumps" and "fox" is the subject of "jumps" (nsubj)

The value 0 is reserved for the root of the tree, usually the main verb of the sentence.